# How do you save a recorded macro in TextMate 2?

Tags: macros, textmate-2

TextMate 2 has a round red button in the bottom right corner of each window that pulses when clicked and records a macro of your actions while it is on.  As far as I can tell the only way to replay a recorded macro is `Edit > Macros > Replay Macro`.

How do you save multiple recorded macros for later use?  After searching the web I have concluded that the previous version of TextMate could save recorded macros via `Bundles > Macros > Save Last Recording...`.  However, TextMate 2 does not have a Macros submenu under the Bundles menu.

Does the current alpha version of TextMate 2 (2.0-alpha.9399) not support saving recorded macros, or am I looking in the wrong places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit → Macros → Save Macro… `⌃⌘M`

(as of very late March 2013)